# Laser induced damage in BBO crystal

Tags: optics, laser, crystals

Does the repetition rate [Hz] of a IR (1035 nm) pulsed laser play a role in the damage threshold of a BBO crystal?

Comment: I shouldn't think so - the damage threshold is mostly dependent on the peak power, though I guess at some point if the repetition rate is extremely fast then you might start interfering with the crystal's ability to dissipate the absorbed energy between one pulse and the next. I'll leave it to the experts to provide a definitive answer, but you should in any case specify which regime you're working in: pulse energy and duration, peak power and peak intensity, and rough repetition rate.

Comment: Thank you Emilio! This isthe regime: (40µJ, 1MHz, 300fs)...In simple words, does the crystal care if I have 1 HZ or 1MHz rep rate?

Comment: I would strongly doubt it, but I'm a theorist so I'll leave it to the people who are actually accountable when they burn stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Because BBO is transparent there really shouldn't be much in the way of heating effects, so it shouldn't play a significant role here, but those are some pretty extreme laser parameters. With 40W of power you'll always be running the risk of damage, but I'd be more concerned about dust or glue damage - is this for a thick BBO, or a thin one on a substrate?

Comment: Hi Allan, thank you for your feedback, its true, dust would also be dangerous. It is a 3mm crystal. The problem is, in the data sheet of the crystal, section damage threshold, there is only the Peak Intensity given, without giving any information about the rep rate...